# How is this answer with 1 vote positioned above an answer with more than 1?

Tags: bug, answers, voting, upvotes

Consider this question:

*[Casting interfaces for deserialization in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780888/casting-interfaces-for-deserialization-in-json-net/40403520#40403520)*

I am just curious, because the answer-positioning seems weird to me.

What's the matter here?

Comment: From what I see, answers are sorted by descending order of votes here, as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was all my fault - layer 8 error so to say. I had answer order by active - I didn't even know this feature existed.

[image: Manual Setting: Order by active]